# Looking for a specific reference, which is used in the book "Lectures on Advanced Computational Methods in Mechanics"

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, reference-works

I need this book "Lectures on Advanced Computational Methods in Mechanics", unfortunately I did not find it in the library of the university .If someone has it, I just want to know the reference [61] used in this book.Thanks.

Comment: It is inane to use a tag as a title, especially one that is not really correct. Just use something like "what is reference 61 in this book?"

Comment: you are right.thanks!

Comment: I have seen that many of your questions have not been marked as answered even though a satisfying response has been given. Please consider marking such a response with a checkmark/tick, so these questions don't appear on the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Marvin Ok ! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a preview on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110195569).

It says [61] J.H. Bramble 'A proof of the inf-sup-condition for the Stokes equations on Lipschitz domains', Math. Models Methods Appl. Sci. 13 (2003) pp.361-371

[image]

The paper can be found [here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bramble/psfiles/infsup1018.pdf).

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much!